# ggplot gantt chart - consistent space between lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data frames, one larger (10 people) and one smaller (two people). I have generated a gantt chart for each data frame. How do I get it so the distance between lines is the same for each plot (i.e. not scaled based on number of entries).

```
# Generate vectors:
name  <- paste("person", seq(10), sep = '_')
start <- sample(seq(5), size = 10, replace = T) 
end <- sample(seq(6,10), size = 10, replace = T) 

# Generate data frames:
big_chart <- data.frame(name = c(name,name), value = c(start,end))
small_chart <- big_chart[c(1:2,11:12),]

# big plot
library(ggplot)
ggplot(big_chart, aes(value, name)) +
  geom_line()

# small plot
ggplot(small_chart, aes(value, name)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my solution for you, hopefully it is what you were looking for. I made use of the `coord_fixed` function to control the overall scaling. In addition, I also fixed your x-axis range using the `xlim` function.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(big_chart, aes(value, name)) +
  geom_line() + 
  xlim(0, 10) + #optional
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.5)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(small_chart, aes(value, name)) +
  geom_line() + 
  xlim(0, 10) + #optional
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.5)
```

[image]